# How to make Python try to load modules from local folder?

Tags: python

I have a Python package that has CLI interface. I would like to work on the package locally and add some features. What is the best way to setup the development environment so that the cli loads the modules defined in the local folder?

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── cli.py
├── diff_augment.py
├── diff_augment_test.py
├── lightweight_gan.py
└── version.py
```

```
python cli.py

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lightweight_gan.diff_augment'; 'lightweight_gan' is not a package
```

If I start up cli.py (python cli.py) it is going to try to load all the modules from the virtualenv instead from the local folder. Is there a way to make Python load the modules first from the local folder?

Comment: Hmm, does python load from first in path, or retain last load from path? Would use of sys.path.insert(<path>,0) help as opposed to sys.path.append(<path>)? or is that inadvisable?

Comment: put folder as first element on list `sys.path`  using `sys.path.insert(0, path)`. And use absolute path instead of relative one. You could try to use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`